# Insert source file between 2 delimters

Tags: bash, sed

I'm trying to replace a part of text file. with another bit of text

Source file:

```
/qwertyae
```

Destination file:

```
abc
def
efg
! unique start
/qwertyad*.$fff|$sdf|$kkr.exe|these.stay.put
! unique end
```

Basically replace /qwertyad with /qwertyae (while keeping the rest of the lines intact). Using Sed (or another method) to insert the source file specifically between ! unique start and ! unique end (and just replace the text between these 2 labels).

desired output:

```
abc
def
efg
! unique start
/qwertyae*.$fff|$sdf|$kkr.exe|these.stay.put
! unique end
```